# It it true that the Fourier transform of the return probability can be written as the product of the retarded propagator & the advanced propagator?

Tags: solid-state-physics, greens-functions

I know the retarded green's function $G(r,r; E)$ is expressed as $$G(r,r; E)=\sum_n \frac{|\mu_n(r)|^2}{E-E_n+i\eta}$$ with the eigenvectors/eigenvalues $\mu_n(r)/E_n$. This expression of $G(r,r; E)$ can be obtained by performing the Fourier transform of $$G(r,t; r,t_0)|_{t>t_0}=\sum_n |\mu_n(r)|^2 e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}E_n(t-t_0)}|_{t>t_0}$$

My question is that, I'm not sure how to get the Fourier transform of $|G(r,t; r,t_0)|_{t>t_0}|^2$, which is basically the return probability  or the so called survival probability since the initial wave-packet is a delta function which goes from $r$ and return back to $r$ in time $(t-t_0)$.

According to some articles, I assume the answer of that is the product of the retarded propagator and the advanced propagator, namely, it should be  $$\sum_{n,m}\frac{|\mu(n)|^2|\mu(m)|^2}{(E-E_n+i\eta)(E-E_m-i\eta)}$$

However, after doing some integration in the complex plane, what I've obtained is $$\sum_{n,m}\frac{|\mu(n)|^2|\mu(m)|^2}{(E-E_n-E_m+i\eta)}$$

Am I doing something wrong? Actually this is my first step for another question that I've came up with. That is, eventually, I would like figure out eq(1) and eq(2) of the paper [PhysRevE.86.021136](http://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.86.021136). I'm puzzled about how the Fourier transform of the ensemble-averaged return probability can be written in the form  , as the authors in that paper have written. Any ideas?

Here's some more information: I realized that my ultimate goal is to know why the Fourier transform of the ensemble-averaged product of the retarded propagator & the advanced propagator, i.e. $<G_R(r,r;E)G_A(r,r,E-w)>=<\sum_{n,m}\frac{|\mu_n(r)|^2|\mu_m(r)|^2}{(E-E_n+i\eta)(E-E_m-w-i\eta)}>$ is related to the disorder-averaged return probability $< \sum_{n,m} |\mu_n(r)|^2|\mu_m(r)|^2 e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}(E_n-E_m)t}>$. I guess the disorder average plays a role here. Maybe a more advanced mathematical tool such as the diagrammatic approach will be necessary?

Comment: "Your" solution and the "some article"'s solution have different dimensions ($1/E$ vs $1/E^2$). This should be a hint to which one is right... Also, the "some article"'s solution can be factored while yours cannot (which should also be a hint).